# Docusign API - Unable to pre-fill fields with validation (Number mask)

Tags: php, json, rest, docusignapi

Successfully sending envelope using PHP/curl to "envelopes" URI, but fields with validation won't receive new values from request.

I have two text fields, one has the "Text" mask and the other has the "Number" mask ("validation" in the NEW DocuSign). The former has an initial value of "ABCD" and the latter has an initial value of "12345". I'd like to change the value of the former to "WXYZ" and the latter to "67890".

Here is the relevant part of the PHP array:

```
"textTabs"    => array(
    array(
        "tabLabel"  => "\\*l_text",
        "value"     => "WXYZ"
    ),
    array(
        "tabLabel"  => "\\*l_contract_number",
        "value"     => "67890"
    )
)
```

that is converted to this JSON with json_encode function:

```
"textTabs":[{"tabLabel":"\\*l_text","value":"WXYZ"},{"tabLabel":"\\*l_contract_number","value":"67890"}]
```

When the document is sent for signing, I see that the `l_text` field's value is now "WXYZ", however `l_contract_number`'s value is still "12345".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a ["Get Tab Information for a Recipient" GET request](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Get%20Tab%20Information%20for%20a%20Recipient.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%2520API%2520References%7C_____87) and discovered that a Text tab becomes a Number tab if you apply the "Number" mask, so I moved it to the "numberTabs" section and now the value is being replaced.

```
"textTabs"    => array(
    array(
        "tabLabel"  => "\\*l_text",
        "value"     => "WXYZ"
    )
),
"numberTabs"    => array(
    array(
        "tabLabel"  => "\\*l_contract_number",
        "value"     => "67890"
    )
)
```